Existing project targeting new .NET version without changes
I'm currently working on a Windows Forms application in Visual Studio. Recently, I noticed that a net6 folder is being created in the bin directory whenever I build my project. This is unexpected, as I haven't manually changed the target framework of my project to .NET 6.
I've checked the .csproj file, and the TargetFramework suddenly changed to net6, without me changing it, neither the Git version control noticing a change.
I suspect that Visual Studio might be automatically updating the target framework to .NET 6, but I'm not sure why this would be happening or how to prevent it. I haven't recently updated Visual Studio or installed a new .NET SDK that could explain this change.
Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any ideas on how to prevent Visual Studio from automatically changing the target framework of my project to .NET 6?

"neither the Git version control noticing a change" that's a strange thing to say. Are you saying that Git hasn't "noticed" changes to the project file? What does the Git history show. Does it show a change at some point in the past? Is the file being ignored (it shouldn't be)

@phuzi it is strange but this is the situation i'm confronting, there are no differences in the .csproj file in the git version control.
